# Создать экземпляр объекта, не вызывая оператор new

Tags: javascript

Задача - это одна из [кат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) на codewars, туплю с решением.

Создать экземпляр объекта, не вызывая оператор new:

```
// Implement the functionality of the 'new' operator as if you had the code:
// var myObj = new MyObject();
// but do not use the 'new' operator.
//
// Start with a simple empty Object literal.
var myObj = {};
```

Тесты для проверки правильности ответа:

```
describe('',function(){
  it('Create a new MyObject', function(){
    Test.expect(myObj instanceof MyObject, 'myObj must be an instance of MyObject');
    Test.expect(myObj.myOwnProperty, 'myObj must be built with the MyObject constructor');
    Test.expect(!myObj.hasOwnProperty('myPrototypeMethod'), 'myObj must use the MyObject prototype');
    Test.expect(myObj.myPrototypeMethod()==true, 'myObj must share the MyObject prototype functions');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Так

```
var myObj=Object.create(MyObject.prototype);
myObj.constructor(); //тут не уверен, может надо присвоить как например для Array
```

http://www.codewars.com/kata/how-new-works

Они хотят почти того же самого, только вместо Object.create присвоить в `__proto__` прототип объекта (на это в FF справедливо выскакивает warning, т.к. оптимизатору предпочтительнее Object.create() ).

Но ката сама кривая, не работают тесты встроенные, а ответ принимает почти какой угодно.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.__proto__ = MyObject.prototype;
myObj.constructor = MyObject;
MyObject.call(myObj);
```